# Removing css for a single link element in html

Tags: html, css

I'm using an `a` tag in my html page which uses a `css` i can't place or modify. 
In the defined `css` `a:link` is styled in a way i dont want to use in my `html` file.

How can i use my `a` tag in order to delete any present styling inherited from the `css`, without modifying the `css` file?

Something like

```
<a href="foo.bar" style="none">foobar</a>
```

maybe?

Remember, for now I cannot modify the `css` file!

Comment: Nope. Sadly you'll have to reset all the CSS styles that are being applied. `style="line-height: normal; color: inherit;` etc. etc.

Comment: 1) Check with what the other links are styled. 2) Find out what the default for these properties is. 3) Put these defaults together in that `<a>`'s attribute.

Comment: Or, just thought of it, give it an ID, then in the CSS file append `:not(#linkID)` to the selector with which you style the other links. That's only slight editing of the CSS file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset all the styles applied to the element, unfortunately.

If for example your anchor tag had the following styles:

```
a {
    color:#f00;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:100px;
    background:#00f;
    text-decoration:none;
    /* Etc... */
}
```

To reset it you'd have to specify:

```
<a href="foo.bar" style="color:#000;font-weight:normal;font-size:16px;background:transparent;text-decoration:underline;<!-- Etc... -->
">foobar</a>
```

Comment: i've found the styles, can you help me setting the defaults? `display:inline-block;
    float:right;
    height:20px;
    width:80px;
    color:#FFF;
    line-height:10px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#666;
    border-radius:3px;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:10px;
    box-shadow:0 1px 0 #000;
    padding:5px;`

Comment: Well the *defaults* are whatever those values should be on your site. At a guess: `display:inline; float:none; height:inherit; width:inherit; color:#00f; line-height:inherit; text-align:left; background-color:transparent; border-radius:0; text-decoration:underline; font-size:16px; box-shadow:none; padding:0;`

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I thought of three ways until now:

1. Find out what styles would apply to this link and put the defaults of these style rules in the `style` attribute of that single `<a>`.
2. Give that `<a>` an ID and append `:not(#linkID)` to the selectors with which you select the other links. That's only slightly editing the CSS file.
3. Put that single link in an `<iframe>`. The CSS of the containing document doesn't affect the content of `<iframe>`s as far as I know.